# Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Every time I try to open Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04 I get an Unsatisfied Link Error and it will not open. I have recently installed the java JDK and Android SDK, could this be the problem? I followed [this tutorial](http://forums.team-nocturnal.com/showthread.php/772).

Here is the log info:

```
!SESSION 2012-04-15 21:05:46.902 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-04-15 21:05:47.885
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
no swt-gtk in java.library.path
Can't load library: /home/tom/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
Can't load library: /home/tom/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and removing the `~/.eclipse` directory but it still doesn't work

Comment: I must say your library path looks odd. Shouldn't those .so files be somewhere within the eclipse/plugins folder, within an exploded jar? Do you even have such a directory (~/.swt/lib/...)?

Comment: Did you install libswt-java-gtk3?

Comment: Although this is answered below, it seems this remains a bug in Ubuntu's installation system that should be raised, because it persists even if I uninstall and reinstall eclipse using aptitude/apt-get. If there's a link to that issue, it would be good to provide it here so folks could upvote it.

Answer (score 662, accepted):

on my Ubuntu 12.04 **32 bit**. I edit the command to:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/
```

And on Ubuntu 12.04 **64 bit** try:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```

Comment: I executed that command exactly as you have it and it worked!  Ubuntu 12.04 with Oracle Java 7

Comment: I'll prefer this method as I have to use Oracle Java 7 for a project

Comment: Thank you. My path was slightly different but this fixed it for me.

`ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/`

Comment: ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/ for 12.04 64-bit

Comment: This is the second time I've had to do this: once on my work computer a few months ago, and just now on my home computer, both times after months of using Eclipse without a single problem. Is there any particular reasons why the swt libraries would just disappear?

Comment: This is real life saver! 
Note whoever on ARM (like me running Eclipse on Chromebook) should replace "x86" with "arm" otherwise it won't work!

Comment: i am facing similar error in linux 64 bit, can anybody check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980558/facing-trouble-launching-spoon-sh-on-amazon-ec2-linux

Comment: For unbuntu 12.04 on MacMini (PPC) the command is ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt* ~/.swt/lib/linux/ppc

Comment: This was the solution for the error caused by using Oracle Java 9 as default on Ubuntu 12.04 when installing Eclipse from Software Center or apt-get repository.

Comment: I executed the command exactly the way its written here but i get this error:

`ln: target ‘/home/latinoheat/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/’ is not a directory: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 54):

SOLVED:

Because I had installed the Oracle Java 7 it had changed the default Java to Oracle Java 7, however it needed to be the Open JDK.

To fix, open up terminal and type

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This brings up a list of the different types of Java. Simply select the Open JDK.

Comment: but what if you'd like to use Oracle Java with eclipse, and not Open JDK, how could one do that? thanks!

Comment: is this because Oracle Java 7 dont look for native library in the Jars anymore? I have a same problem on windows with Java 7 as well. the swt program used to be work just fine

Comment: Worked for me for linux mint maya.

Comment: Of course, if you prefer FOSS, OpenJDK is the platform of choice, but (as usual with these corporate troglodytes) Oracle imposes certain hooks in their version that prevents porting of some apps (and most java webstart apps) between java platforms. This defeats the main objective of Java, namely portability, which is why they are shooting themselves in the foot by practicing vendor lock-in... Long Live the Python! Long Live!

Answer (score 44):

Simply specify the path to the libraries:

```
echo "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni/" >> /etc/eclipse.ini
```

Comment: Seems that this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Agree, cleanest and this method will permanently avoid the error on an Ubuntu system that is prone to Java version changes - given the side-effect of OpenJDK upgrades to reconfigure java related file locations

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 64-bit
Cleanest solution indeed, I recommend anyone pick this solution instead of creating the symlinks

Comment: this is the one to use if your using oracle java 7 and not open JDK

Comment: The most voted answer works, but not for when you "sudo eclipse". 
This answer is superior, it works in all cases!

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I was missing the `/usr/lib/jni` directory entirely. Fixed by

```
sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java
```

No need to symlink afterwards. Eclipse started normally.

Comment: After installing jni. I copied files using this command for 32 bit:  ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/

Comment: In my case, I needed
    sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-4-jni libswt-gtk-4-java

Comment: @padman Copying files that were installed by package management (APT in this case) is *not* a good idea. The copied files *won't* be under package management and you risk getting all kinds of other errors later on when the files under package management get upgraded. Instead, find a way to point your Eclipse to the correct location of these libraries (see dzlatkov 's answer above).

Answer (score 9):

For Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) you'll need

```
apt install libswt-gtk-4-jni
```

If you don't have an OpenJDK 8 you'll also need

```
apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: I am using `openjdk-17-jdk`, and just doing `apt install libswt-gtk-4-jni` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
Can't load library: /home/tom/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
Can't load library: /home/tom/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so
```

looks like the libraries should be at  .swt/lib/linux/x86_64/ if there are not there you can 
try  this command:

```
locate  libswt-gtk.so
```

this should find the libraries copy the entire directory to  /home/tom/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64

Comment: i am facing similar error in linux 64 bit, can you check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980558/facing-trouble-launching-spoon-sh-on-amazon-ec2-linux

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Scott, what he listed worked. However just running it from any directory did not work. I had to cd to the /home/*****/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/ 0 files

directory first and then run the link command:

For 32 bit:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/
```

And on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```

Answer (score 3):

On redhat7 :

```
yum install gtk2 libXtst xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

did the job, because of a swt dependency.

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34801118/1767316)

Answer (score 2):

If you start eclipse using oracle java, then eclipse might fail in finding native libraries like SWT or SVN libraries. The SWT-JNI libraries are located in /usr/lib/jni/ and the SVN-JNI libraries are located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/.

Instead of starting eclipse with the command

```
eclipse
```

you can use the command

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jni/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH eclipse
```

to pass the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to eclipse. Eclipse will find the native libraries and will run properly.

Comment: This gives me this error `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage (file:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage`

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error when tried to start 32-bit build of Eclipse under 64-bit linux. The problem was solved after installing ia32-libs package.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your home partition is mounted with executable permissions. That is the default, but if you happen to mount it without exec option, you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

A possibly more generic method is to:

- install non-headless version of the openjdk,
- install, run and close eclipse.
- uninstall the openjdk
- install oracle's JDK

Answer (score 0):

I installed the JDK 32 bit because of that I am getting the errors. After installing JDK 64 bit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz(please download the 64 version)
and download  64 bit "eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz".