# eclipse on ubuntu: what is missing from my configuration?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to follow [these](http://lackovic.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/set-up-eclipse-and-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-12-04-to-create-java-restful-web-services-with-jersey/) instructions to set up a java development environment under ubuntu 12.04.

However, I think something is missing from my configuration.

I installed eclipse, and added the Web, XML and java development package in step 2.  The default JVM is:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Tomcat is installed, and I can see & run the samples from localhost:8080

But when I try to add a new server (step 4) there is no "Server" under preferences; and when I create a new "Dynamic Web Project" (step 5) there's no options there.

When I try switching perspectives, all I have is "CVS Repository Exploring", "Debug", "Resource (default)" and "Team Synchronizing".

I'm obviously missing something (hopefully simple) - but why can't I seem to get set up for java development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I tried to start with a fresh install.  I removed eclipse using the software center and then manually deleted /etc/eclipse.ini

I also remove my default workspace (~/workspace) and .eclipse

I then reinstalled Eclipse, and followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7) to install the oracle java 7.

There was a problem, which was resolved by following the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/ubuntu-eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries-not-opening) question.

Then, I installed the Web, XML and Java EE plugins from Help->Install New Software, and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably downloaded the wrong version of Eclipse / not installed enough packages.

Did you download Eclipse for Java or Eclipse for Java EE Developers?  I believe the servers is only included in Eclipse for Java EE.

Instead of trying to add the extra packages, I'd recommend just getting Java EE edition.  It'll come with all those other XML & Web packages you need, and any other missing dependencies.

Comment: I believe I installed the J2EE verion - under the Platform Installation Details, it lists both The Eclipse Java Development Tools and Eclipse Java EE Developer tools (and the Java web development tools, etc)

Comment: Is your downloaded ZIP > 200mb?  If so you got that right.  However, the 'server' listing is standard in Eclipse, so I'm not sure why else it wouldn't be listed.  Just double check which one you got.

Comment: I installed it from the Ubuntu software center, and then installed the additional components from the updater.  I'm going to try installing the sun (oops...oracle) java ee 6 sdk and see if that helps.

Comment: I doubt that would make any additional options appear through Eclipse... but it is possible that it's hiding 'Server' when the EE libraries aren't found.  Post your result.