# Aptana version 3.4.2.201308081805 crash

Tags: aptana3

I have Aptana version 3.4.2.201308081805  on Linux Mint 15 64bit
was open just once and now anytime when I want to start the Aptana crash
here is the one from a few crash log:

```
   #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007fab6e08a938, pid=4403, tid=140373276522240
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x4938]  Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_getZipMessage+0x8d8
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use OpenJDK

Use Java 7 from the wbupd8 repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Prerequirements

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

If you got problems with SWT take a look at

[Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by removing openjdk and installing oracle jdk.

The step by step instruction is provided in the following article
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

so far no crash in aptana.

FYI: I am using lubuntu

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the crash even with oracle jdk. Finally, I decided to install Eclipse from package manager and install aptana plugin for eclipse.