# Eclipse-based IDE, LPCXpresso, doesn't launch because of SWT library not loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, swt

I'm having trouble with LPCXpresso IDE. I'm unable to launch it.

Here is a part of the log file :

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
>     /home/fouge/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_470841845/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/213/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4236.so:
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun
>   fichier ou dossier de ce type

I found help saying I need to make a symbolic link :

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/  # for 32-bit OS
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/ # for 64-bit OS
```

Like said on this post :
[Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries/10251453#10251453)

But the problem is I don't have /usr/lib/**jni** directory ! 
I'm running Ubuntu 13.10

The question should be where are SWT library files ?

Comment: I have more information.

There is libswt-pi-gtk-4236.so file in the given directory.
The problem seems to come from libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0. I found this file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions do not sound correct (or good). The versions of Eclipse, Java, and GTK+2 all have to be 32-bit or 64-bit *together*. If you have a mismatch, resolve the mismatch.

Where was this help found?

Comment: The link is in my post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries/10251453#10251453

Comment: LPCXpresso is 32bit.

I'm installing 32bit JDK because it was 64bit (`$ java -version`)
`$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre:i386`
...
It works ! Thank you !