# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3139 in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I am making simple java Desktop application using eclipse in Linux. I have added all required libraries in to my class path. but I still getting this error when I run this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3139 in java.library.path
```

I was trying to find an answer through Internet but still I can not. Can anybody help me. I am using SWT designer to implement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had this kind of error too.
[Eclipse-based IDE, LPCXpresso, doesn't launch because of SWT library not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069412/eclipse-based-ide-lpcxpresso-doesnt-launch-because-of-swt-library-not-loaded)

> The versions of Eclipse, Java, and GTK+2 all have to be 32-bit or
>   64-bit together

Answer (score -1):

Google is your friend (second hit when searching for "swt-pi-gtk-3139"): http://blog.headius.com/2006/04/eclipse-unsatisfiedlinkerror-libswt-pi.html.

From the error alone [it is apparent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) that a function or class cannot be found and that you therefore are missing libraries or are using the wrong ones.