# facing trouble launching spoon.sh on amazon ec2 linux

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, classpath, pentaho, kettle

I am quit new to linux and Amazon EC2.

i configure JAVA_HOME by following below two link

[How to know JAVA_HOME_Variable](http://www.igoy.in/java-home-directory-for-linux/)

[bash_profile](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/)

so current path in my bash_profile are

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64/bin
```

now i am trying to launch ./spoon.sh it is giving me error of

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
    no swt-pi-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
    no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
    /root/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-3740.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /root/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk.so

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:540)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
```

so can somebody suggest that what is wrong?

Comment: i installed Java SWT, but same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pentaho do not supports the openjdk java version. **Install the the Oracle/Sun java.**

But anyway... Are you trying to run the kettle environment on a Ec2 instance? without X screen?
If you want simply to run kettle jobs or transformations you have to use **kitchen.sh or pan.sh** , not spoon.sh. Spoon.sh is only to create the trans or jobs with a GUI interface.

Comment: thanks for reply, you are right i was trying to run kettle environment on ec2 instance, i removed openjdk and installed oracle java, but i am using cassandra as a database so i configured my pdi with big data pluggin https://support.pentaho.com/entries/24445558-Big-Data-Plugin-Version-1-3-3-for-Pentaho-BA-Server-4-8-1-x-and-PDI-4-4-1-x(followed this link), so now at the time of launching ./kitchen.sh it is giving me error  Unable to load Hadoop Configuration from "file:///dev/pdi/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/mapr21" so how can i resolve this?

Comment: and same thing for pan.sh

Comment: i use pdi 4.4 version and always get this warning, if your jobs and trans works ok  ignore the error, if not: try to run kitchen.sh or pan.sh from the pdi directory. http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-5076

Comment: thanks for your reply,
for now i removed "pentaho-big-data-plugin" this folder, now i want to run my job, i am giving below command,
./kitchen.sh -job=jobname.kjb (here how can i give the location of kjb file)
because it is giving me error of job couldn't be loaded.

Comment: i am able to execute kitchen with in this way <pdi_dist>/pdi-ee/data-integration/kitchen.sh -file <trans_job_folder>/ 
runHdoopFileInput.kjb -norep,

is their any way to open kettle in amazon ec2 instance, so that i can analyse history, logging, job metrics. so how can i do similar thing?

Comment: Forget about to use Kettle as production tool, kettle is just for development. You could write the output log to a file by adding this param to your execution line: sh pan.sh -file="/bla/bla/yourTransformation.ktr" -param:ROUTE_TO_LOG="/tmp/myTransOutput.log"

Answer (score 0):

You have exported the wrong path of JAVA_HOME. It should be the as below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

Comment: i did the changes you mention but the same problem, didn't work.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. Does /home/nifty/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk.so exits ?

Comment: After changing the JAVA_HOME, you will have to restart your terminal or use "source .bashrc"

Comment: i restarted before i comment, how to check whether libswt-pi-gtk exist?

Comment: use: ls -lrt /home/nifty/.swt/lib/linux/x86

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48247/discussion-between-working-hard-and-rahul)

Comment: what does echo $JAVA_HOME return ?   using the root user for something like eclipse is usually a bad idea. Funny thing is that I dont have this library in my OS I have  it  in my yoxos bundle (yoxos is a eclipse "package manager" try it if everything fails)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see here is that the yum repository for EC2 Amazon Linux AMI instance does not include any graphical binaries. These binaries include gtk and swt with gtk. You can either compile all dependencies or use another image. Since you are a newbie, I suggest you switch to an ubuntu image.

On an ubuntu image, you should be able to run apt-get to install missing dependencies:

For Java:
 - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java for oracle java
 - sudo apt-get update
 - sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

For libswt:
 - sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java

Another issue I can think of is that you are likely trying to run a graphical application. If that is the case, you will have to run it with a window manager like Xvnc or Xvfb.