# Pentaho BI Server - Charting live data

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I have a URL that produces JSON,

```
{
"status": "success",
"totalRecords": 55,
"records": [
    {
        "timestamp": 1393418044341,
        "load": 40,
        "deviceId": 285
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1393418104337,
        "load": 42,
        "deviceId": 285
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1393418164328,
        "load": 24.5,
        "deviceId": 285
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1393418224322,
        "load": 42.5,
        "deviceId": 285
    },
```

It goes on and on, producing data every 30 seconds or so.
I have used Pentaho data-integration to parse and extract each of the data and put them into individual groups - `timestamp`, `load` and `deviceId`.
When I saved this it produced a .ktr file.

From this i have used the report-designer to upload the .ktr file and make charts with the data and then I uploaded the charts to the BI Server.

BUT

Can I just take the data, feed it into the BI Server and produce charts, bypassing the report-designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this - and using report designer would definately be the wrong way.

However you've inadvertantly made the right choice in building the first bit in PDI!  Thats a good move.

Next step is to install CTools, add your .ktr to a CDA datasource (within CDE) and then using CDE define your charts and finally a refresh interval on the dashboard.

There's lots of good CTools tutorials around if you havent used it yet - it is also easily installed from the marketplace, or via ctools-installer.sh

Comment: Cheers dude, never used or heard of CTools before but I will look into it and see how it can be done

Comment: @codek can you look at this question ? on mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980558/facing-trouble-launching-spoon-sh-on-amazon-ec2-linux

Comment: @Codek I have got CTools up and going and now need to get the .ktr to the CDA datasource. I have tried many variations of this but none are working, have you any ideas how this can be done?