# Ubuntu now able to set java path

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, classpath, pentaho

I have installed oracle jdk in /usr/lib/jvm/ and i have setted up path in etc/environment as

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

But still when i am running javac, I am getting following error. The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:

```
* default-jdk
* ecj
* gcj-4.6-jdk
* gcj-4.7-jdk
* openjdk-7-jdk
* openjdk-6-jdk
```

It means javac is not installed or java path has not setted properly, however i am able to see javac,java,jps and other programs in my /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51. I have searched enough about it but still not able to get solution of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `/etc/environment` is not a file executed by the shell (like a shell script); you cannot use `$SOMETHING` references in this file. Variables are not substituted in this file. So,

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

the second line will not work like this. You have to put the exact path in.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51
PATH=...:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin
```

Comment: Alternatively, put the path to javac in /etc/profile instead of in /etc/environment.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/78856/referencing-environment-variables-in-etc-environment

Comment: @jesper can you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980558/facing-trouble-launching-spoon-sh-on-amazon-ec2-linux

Answer (score 2):

The `javac` binary (and probably other java binaries) is/are not in your user's `$PATH` environment variable. There are several ways you can address this:

1. Add `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin` to your user's $PATH
   environment variable. You can do this by adding a line similar to
   the following in your user's .bash_profile:

   `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin`

You'll have to restart your terminal session for it to take effect.

Create symbolic links to the java binaries from some directory
    that's already part of your path (such as `/usr/bin`)

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java /usr/bin/
 sudo ln-s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac /usr/bin/
```

BTW: There are several other java executables in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin.` see  the symlink commands for java and javac above. You should run similar command for any other executables you may want to use.

Use the fully qualified path directly on the command line:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac
```

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

have you tried this page? Its where I go when I need Java info. You may not have the one you installed set as default.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you did not refresh the shell after change in path variable?

if you echo $PATH are the changes present?

Comment: hey when i am DOING echo$PATH changes are not present