# Grails: GGTS not running on Amazon AWS EC2 anyone else successful?

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm just curious if anyone has had success trying to run the Groovy Grails tool suite on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance with its display exported into your windows machine. If so, I wanted to know which flavor of linux was used on the EC2. I am not having much success with it on the Amazon Linux but haven't tried their Ubuntu instances yet. I got all the way to getting GGTS installed and getting the display exported but when I launch GGTS I get log errors about libraries missing. This is most likely because I didn't use yum to install it so I am probably missing dependencies but I didn't have a choice its not offered as a yum package. Here are my log file errors when I try to launch GGTS:

```
!SESSION 2014-06-08 03:08:04.873 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.5.1.201405030657-RELEASE-e43
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.ggts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.springsourc
e.ggts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-06-08 03:08:12.116
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
    /home/ec2-user/ggts_sh/ggts-3.5.1.RELEASE/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi
/bundles/704/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4335.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open share
d object file: No such file or directory
     no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/ec2-user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4335.so: libgtk-x11-2
.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /home/ec2-user/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk.s
o

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(
IDEApplication.java:154)
       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEAppli
cation.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandl
e.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runAppli
cation(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ec
lipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.ja
va:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.ja
va:181)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run GGTS using Ec2 Ubuntu instead. All needed packages are there without the dependency headache. I have been successful in getting GGTS running in Ec2 Ubuntu with display exported onto my Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is similar to : [facing trouble launching spoon.sh on amazon ec2 linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980558/facing-trouble-launching-spoon-sh-on-amazon-ec2-linux/32209996#32209996)

You are missing the following libraries: libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java. Either you have to recompile them (and all transitive dependencies like GTK), or use another image like Ubuntu from which you can simply do a apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java.