# i can't open eclipse after installing it from ubuntu center

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, ubuntu-12.04

Just I installed Eclipse from Ubuntu software center and I try to open eclipse but its showing error like go and check log file. And I opened that log file their showing error like this.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-03-21 15:30:05.439
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path`` 
no swt-gtk in java.library.path Can't load library: /root/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so Can't load library: /root/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so
```

how can i solve this problem,can any one help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries  .. Have you checked this out

Comment: Now i checked its working now thank you.