# Why is Eclipse not finding swt libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, libraries

I have the following issue: after having installed `jdk-6u22-linux-i586.bin` and `eclipse-SDK-3.5.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz`, when I'm launching Eclipse, the SWT libraries can not be found.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries) and [this](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#missingdll).

Since I do not have any `/usr/lib/jni` directory on my machine, I've come to the conclusion I had to un-jar the `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_5.5.2.v3557f.jar` file to get the .so library. I've have relaunched eclipse, including the extraction directory in the java path. The issue still remains:

I have the following error message (notice the addition of `-Djava.library.path=...` in the command line):

```
!SESSION 2015-06-03 14:52:10.343
-----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20100211-1343
java.version=1.6.0_22
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -Djava.library.path=/path.to.the.eclipse.plugins.dir/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.5.2.v3557f
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -consoleLog -Djava.library.path=/path.to.the.eclipse.plugins.dir/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.5.2.v3557f

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository 4 0 2015-06-03 14:52:10.764
!MESSAGE ProvisioningEventBus could not be obtained. Metadata caches may not be cleaned up properly.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-06-03 14:52:12.119
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3557 or swt-pi-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:254)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:159)
etc.
```

The `libswt-pi-gtk-3557.so` library is indeed inside the `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.5.2.v3557f` directory, so no joke here. But I do not understand why the program keeps telling me the library can not be found.

Comment: Can you check what java are you running by java -version in terminal. Also you might have to set up correct path in environment variable as well as the eclipse ini file.

Comment: Ok, I was using 32-bit Java and 32-bit Eclipse on a 64-bit machine (because other software seemed to be needed this version). Using both 64-bit versions of Java and Eclipse solved the issue! Thanks for your input anyway!

Comment: I'm still curious of what the issue might be with 32-bit versions, though...

Comment: You can't link 32-bit SWT natives with 64-bit GTK+ natives.

Comment: How should I proceed, then, if I want to install 32-bit Java and 32-bit Eclipse on a 64-bit machine? Should I install 32-bit GTK libraries? Is that possible?