# MQ Explorer - Could not load SWT library

Tags: linux, swt, ibm-mq

Installed IBM MQ 8.0.0.4 developer instance in Linux VM (Centos).

When launching MQ explorer, using command strmqcfg (getting the following error).

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-14 13:33:43.226
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        /home/mqm/.eclipse/com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.RcpApplication_8.0.0.201510171407_1624510073_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/500/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4333.so (libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
        swt-pi-gtk (Not found in java.library.path)
        /home/mqm/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4333.so (libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
        /home/mqm/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk.so (/home/mqm/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/liblibswt-pi-gtk.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
        at com.ibm.mq.explorer.ui.rcp.internal.base.RcpApplication.start(RcpApplication.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

I see online that there is download of SWT libraries for AIX. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21631478

Is there a similar download for Linux CentOS. Appreciate any help. Is the resolution different for CentOS.

Here is machine info:
java -version

```
java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (rhel-1.13.6.1.el6_6-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

dspmqver

```
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     8.0.0.4
Level:       p800-004-151017
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    /opt/IBM/mqm
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 802
LicenseType: Developer
```

Answer (score 4):

Use yum to install these packages:

```
gtk2 libXtst xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

Some graphical pieces of WebSphere Application Server have the same SWT dependencies -- the way the prereqs are documented for RHEL7 is here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tins_linuxsetup_rhel7.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en

Comment: hi, can't use yum because of restricted environment. Is there official source of download for these RPMs. Product installed is Websphere MQ (not websphere app server).

Comment: The RPM's are available from centos.org. You'll have to resolve the dependencies manually by trial and error if you can't use the higher level tools provided with the OS.

Comment: It still doesn't load after installing the libraries following the link.

Comment: rg.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed],

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answer.

I know this is an old post....but just wanted to add that the solution is still relevant today in case anyone has a similar issue. Installing `gtk2 libXtst` is exactly and precisely what I needed to resolve an issue with not being able to launch IIB10 Toolkit on Manjaro (kernel 5.9). For reference, the *error* I got *prior to installing these 2 packages* was:

```
JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20200724_452227 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 4ce4b9d
OMR      - 08b0594
IBM      - 70917a2
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -showlocation -product com.ibm.etools.msgbroker.tooling.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showlocation -product com.ibm.etools.msgbroker.tooling.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-01-10 14:21:08.900
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
        /home/user1/IBM/IIBT10-config/10.0.0.22/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1177/0/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4430.so (libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No
 such file or directory)
        swt-pi-gtk (Not found in java.library.path)
        /home/user1/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4430.so (libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
        /home/user1/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk.so (/home/user1/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/liblibswt-pi-gtk.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or dir
ectory)

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:757)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
```