# Cannot start eclipse due to swt libraries on Windows 8

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I'm having problems starting up eclipse on my windows 8 computer. Understand that this question has been posted already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries?rq=1) but it seems to be for ubuntu. I know nothing about computers so it would be really helpful if someone could guide me through solving this problem.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-02-13 18:10:53.990
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
C:\Users\Zhan Feng\eclipse\java-mars\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\388\0\.cp\swt-win32-4528.dll: Invalid access to memory location
no swt-win32 in java.library.path
Can't load library: C:\Users\Zhan Feng\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4528.dll
Can't load library: C:\Users\Zhan Feng\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
C:\Users\Zhan Feng\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4528.dll: Invalid access to memory location

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:327)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:236)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:16)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:734)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:111)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: Are you running 64-bit or 32-bit windows?

Comment: 64-bit, but i think i've got the 32 bit version of eclipse installed. was working perfectly fine before