# android java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, sdk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Background:

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in a VirtualBox VM and I am trying to set up some dependencies in order to start playing around with the PhoneGap framework. Namely Java SE and Android SDK. First, I installed the Android SDK by following this tutorial: http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/ (at step 5). 
Then, I realized I didn't have Java SE so I followed this tutorial: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux.

The Problem:

After I installed the Android SDK, I could easily run the  command to open up the SDK manager. After installing the Java SE, I get the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3550 or swt-pi-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:403)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:391)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

I assume that this has something to do with the fact that I removed some version of OpenJDK in order to install Java, as per the tutorial. I've tried to search for this error, with all the fixes suggesting the command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

After which I get an error saying:

```
mount: /tmp not mounted or bad option
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to this thread: [Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries)

"Because I had installed the Oracle Java 7 it had changed the default Java to Oracle Java 7, however it needed to be the Open JDK.

To fix, open up terminal and type

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This brings up a list of the different types of Java. Simply select the Open JDK."

Comment: This solution worked for me.  No idea how I ended up needing this, but
    sudo update-alternatives --config java
worked, and I selected
  0       /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071     auto mode

Answer (score 0):

## On Gallium OS

```
cd /tmp
chmod +x swtlib-64
```

Then when you do:

```
android
```

SDK Manager shows up..
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with an older Android installation and Java headless in a container.
Installing package `libswt-gtk-3-java` solved it for me

```
apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-java
```