# Eclipse CDT 4.11.0 crashes with SWT library not found error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-2019-03

I am trying to get Eclipse 4.11.0 running on my RHEL 6.10 system but it crashes when I try to run it.  It points me to a log file that states:

> ...UnsatisfiedLinkError org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._cachejvmptr()V

I tried running it again and it crashed again with a different log file entry:

> ...UnsatisfiedLinkError Could not load SWT library

It was looking for:

> ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi4-gtk-4924r25.so

but the only file in that directory was libswt-pi3-gtk-4924r25.so
I also found libswt-pi3-gtk-4924r25.so in eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/458/0/.cp.
I removed my ~/.swt directory and ran it again.  Once again I got:

> ...UnsatisfiedLinkError org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._cachejvmptr()V

I noticed that it made the ~/.swt/… directory structure and put the libswt-pi3-gtk-4924r25.so file in it so I tried to run it again and it (not surprisingly) gave me the following:

> ...UnsatisfiedLinkError Could not load SWT library

Does this have something to do with the version of gtk that I'm running on my system?
  Why does eclipse include the libswt-pi3-gtk.4924r25.so library in their installation, then look for the libswt-pi4-gtk-4924r25.so library?

Comment: [1] [Is this link relevant](https://forum.kaosx.us/d/2358-error-with-eclipse) for your problem? _"This is solved by creating a symlink to ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi3-gtk-4924r25.so Then Eclipse can be launched."_ [2] Also see this (very old) SO question: [Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10165693/2985643) [3] If they don't help I suggest adding tags for _eclipse_ and _eclipse-2019-03_ to your question to attract a wider audience.

Comment: @skomisa - I tried [1] but I got an error stating it couldn't find ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi3-gtk-4924r25.so.  I also looked into [2] and my system doesn't have a /usr/lib/jni directory.

Answer (score 0):

Installing libgthread resolved the issue for me (SLES15, GTK3).