# Trying to setup eclipse inside a docker container with access over X11 via Xming

Tags: java, eclipse, docker

As the title says, I am trying to set up a docker container which contains an ubuntu:20.10 image with openjdk and eclipse. The eclipse workspace is mounted. I am installing eclipse manually by copying the files from the tar.gz archive into the container. Eclipse begins to start but does result in the error

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Eclipse:
An error has occurred. See the log file
```

I have tried switching the Java version, mounting a workspace inside the docker container and other things ppl suggested online. I also read that the error can be ignored and eclipse will start anyways, but the error cannot be ignored when it comes to docker. It will shut down the container when any executions return 1.

I am looking for one of two solutions, with the goal of getting the container up and running, displaying eclipse via X11 to my Xming server. (The Xming server config works, i've tried it with a firefox container first).

1. Fix the error that prevents eclipse from starting. Desirable solution, as this would increase my understanding of why the f this is happening.
2. Make the Shell script that starts eclipse ignore that error and continue to start. Not clean, but hey it works.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

P.S: I am aware that there are better alternatives like the eclipse/che image, but I want to figure it out this way to try some stuff which eclipse/che wont work with. Thaks!

Comment: `ssh -Y <docker image>` and verify that `xterm` works. Once that works, try `eclipse`.

Comment: That first line is not an error. Look in the log file.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch As already stated, I verified that my execution with X11 works with the same container but only a firefox instance running. That worked flawlessly.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks! for some reason i thought those two were connected. I now will try to resolve the starting errors eclipse gives to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.

This message is not an error as suggested by @greg-449. I was missing the swt library gtk and java versions which can be installed with apt-get, as solved here:

[Eclipse cannot load SWT libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries)