# Server Error with sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11

Tags: google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I have been successfully developing with Google AppEngine/Android C2DM stuff for many months now.

Suddenly, after updating with all the latest Android and AppEngine dev SDK's etc., even the Eclipse built in "App Engine Connected Android Project" (from the Google Plugin for Eclipse) gives the following server error when testing the C2DM:

> Server Error: Could not initialize class sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and the solution was to choose a different JDK. Not sure if this is your case too but here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034900/appengine-devmode-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission-accessclassinp) to the SO question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @koma .   Can you please give detailed instructions on your comments in that link concerning "setup JAVA_HOME and PATH"

Comment: define the newly installed JRE in eclipse->preferences->"installed JREs" and then assign the JRE to the project and rebuilt the project.

Comment: Thanks @koma, that did it!  It was a complete stroke of luck that you had a similar problem.  Everytime Google updates anything with AppEngine or Android I have problems like this.  How in the world does this stuff get through Google everytime?