# google-app-engine eclipse policyutil.getKeyStore illegalarguementexception can't start debug environment

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I can't seem to start my development environment for gae on eclipse anymore.  Once I start it it goes to the debug view with source not found for the PolicyUtil.getKeyStore with an illegalarguementexception.  Has anyone else had this problem?  I've tried deleting my run configs but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.  Here's the stack trace:

```
{Daemon Thread [Thread-1] (Suspended (exception IllegalArgumentException))  
    PolicyUtil.getKeyStore(URL, String, String, String, String, Debug) line: 65 
    PolicyFile.init(URL, PolicyFile$PolicyInfo) line: 635   
    PolicyFile.access$400(PolicyFile, URL, PolicyFile$PolicyInfo) line: 266 
    PolicyFile$3.run() line: 546    
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>) line: not available [native method]  
    PolicyFile.initPolicyFile(String, String, PolicyFile$PolicyInfo) line: 519  
    PolicyFile.initPolicyFile(PolicyFile$PolicyInfo, URL) line: 505 
    PolicyFile.init(URL) line: 464  
    PolicyFile.<init>() line: 309   
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor, Object[]) line: not available [native method]   
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 39    
    DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 27    
    Constructor<T>.newInstance(Object...) line: 513 
    Class<T>.newInstance0() line: 355   
    Class<T>.newInstance() line: 308    
    Policy.getPolicyNoCheck() line: 167 
    ProtectionDomain.implies(Permission) line: 224  
    AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Permission) line: 352  
    AccessController.checkPermission(Permission) line: 546  
    SecurityManager.checkPermission(Permission) line: 532   
    Policy.getPolicy() line: 133    
    SecurityManagerInstaller.install(URL...) line: 81   
    DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(File, File, File, String, int, boolean, boolean, Map<String,Object>) line: 136   
    DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(File, File, File, String, int, boolean) line: 78 
    DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(File, String, int) line: 52  
    DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply() line: 175  
    Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs() line: 48 
    DevAppServerMain.<init>(String[]) line: 128 
    DevAppServerMain.main(String[]) line: 104}
```

I went on and downloaded the latest for GAE and the eclipse plugin hoping that would fix it but no luck.

Regards,
John

Comment: maybe it is the same prob as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034900/appengine-devmode-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission-accessclassinp

Comment: I don't have openJDK installed.  The errors look different.

Comment: both stacktraces have pass thru AccessControlContext.checkPermission. You are not by any chance using Java 7 ?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  See my fix below.  Frustrating error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - My workspace was corrupt.  I created a new workspace folder and had to import my project and settings.