# addition of GWT Breaks Cloud SQL JPA using Eclipse GPE

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, jpa-2.0, google-apps, google-cloud-sql

I've tested multiple times some strange behavior exhibited by Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE) when running a project both a JPA facet persisting to Google Cloud SQL and GWT.  I'm using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo, AppEngine 1.6.5, EclipseLink 2.3 JPA, and GWT 2.4.0.

I successfully set up JPA 2.0 with GPE following the [directions](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools) .  Then, once that's working, I then try to check "use GWT" in the GPE "Google" menu for the project.  At that very point, JPA persistence to the Google Cloud SQL breaks.  This is reversible by unchecking "use GWT", luckily.  I'm using the Cloud SQL for development, not the local MySQL.  I want to test that next.

Here is my stacktrace for the connection error that pops up after checking "use GWT".  The short of it is: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11".

```
    [EL Severe]: 2012-06-13 02:47:02.408--ServerSession(4315167)--com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request rdbms.OpenConnection().
Jun 13, 2012 2:47:02 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /jpatest
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request rdbms.OpenConnection().
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:272)
    at com.myproject.JpatestServlet.doGet(JpatestServlet.java:14)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$UnknownException: An error occurred for the API request rdbms.OpenConnection().
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:518)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:452)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:493)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:490)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:262)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:244)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:244)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:224)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:232)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(ProviderList.java:330)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:157)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:696)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:130)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(AlgorithmId.java:121)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:114)
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(AlgorithmId.java:381)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:168)
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:705)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:169)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1747)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:196)
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:107)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:322)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:763)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1201)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.getTrustStore(LocalURLFetchService.java:190)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.createValidatingScheme(LocalURLFetchService.java:206)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.createHttpClient(LocalURLFetchService.java:252)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.init(LocalURLFetchService.java:298)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.startServices(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:581)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.access$700(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:46)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:564)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.getService(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:561)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.resolveDeadline(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:233)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.doAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:147)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:297)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:89)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:814)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi$DefaultGoogleApi.execImpl(RpcGoogleApi.java:346)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi$DefaultGoogleApi.exec(RpcGoogleApi.java:322)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.internal.googleapi.RpcGoogleApi.openConnection(RpcGoogleApi.java:100)
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsServiceRemoteDriver.openConnection(LocalRdbmsServiceRemoteDriver.java:206)
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsService.openConnection(LocalRdbmsService.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:498)
    ... 10 more
```

and here are my connection parameters in the Eclipse run configuration, after adding in GWT:

```
    -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -war /home/eric/workspace/jpatest/war -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -port 8888 com.myproject.jpatest
Just JPA: --port=8888 /home/eric/workspace/jpatest/war


VM
-Drdbms.password= -Drdbms.user= -Drdbms.database=compass -Drdbms.hosted.instance=ejahn.net:openciss:compasslight -Drdbms.server=hosted -Xmx512m -javaagent:/home/eric/eclipse/appengine-java-sdk-1.6.5/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.  I'll try to share this with Google as well, since I think it is something they ultimately need to be aware of.

Comment: what version of jdk are you using ? have you tried with another ?

Comment: have a look at this maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034900/appengine-devmode-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission-accessclassinp .. as @jonasr says, could be a JDK issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally get it to work.  I'm not actually sure what was the ultimate fix, but making sure my drivers were all connecting fine in the database development perspective in Eclipse, making sure my persistence.xml hadn't been change from the original (below), removing any IDE complaints/errors/warnings, and making sure my persistence units were correctly defined did the trick.  A lot of moving parts... Thanks for the encouragement and thoughts, jonasr!

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://mydomain.net:myappengine:myinstance/mydb"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
```