# gwt-dev.jar conflicts with icu jar on war/lib classpath when using GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, conflict, icu

Ok I have to rewrite my question after further investigation.

I run into below problem in my GWT/GAE project :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime$21 can not access a member of class com.ibm.icu.text.CollatorServiceShim with modifiers ""
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Collator.getShim(Collator.java:456)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Collator.getInstance(Collator.java:478)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.datatable.value.TextValue$1.<init>(TextValue.java:126)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.datatable.value.TextValue.getTextLocalizedComparator(TextValue.java:125)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.datatable.value.Value$1.<init>(Value.java:141)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.datatable.value.Value.getLocalizedComparator(Value.java:140)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.query.engine.TableRowComparator.<init>(TableRowComparator.java:66)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.query.engine.QueryEngine.performSort(QueryEngine.java:234)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.query.engine.QueryEngine.executeQuery(QueryEngine.java:128)
    at com.google.visualization.datasource.DataSourceHelper.applyQuery(DataSourceHelper.java:410)
    at com.klawt.server.resources.chart.InvoicesChartServerResource.retrieve(InvoicesChartServerResource.java:129)
```

Some more investigation revealed that **gwt-dev.jar** contains a copy of the icu library :

> public abstract class com.ibm.icu.text.Collator implements
>   java.util.Comparator, com.ibm.icu.util.Freezable

is part of gwt-dev.jar

My project has a dependency on icu4j 4.0.1 (for the [Google Visualization Datasource library](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-java/)). But GAE SDK insists on using the version included in gwt-dev.jar;

I guess there must a way to setup my development environment so this kinda works, it did before.

I have tried moving GWT SDK to the bottom in the 'Order and export' tab of my build path and the icu jar to the top, but no luck.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: is this server-side code? Is your icu4j JAR in `WEB-INF/lib`? What if you also remove it from the DevMode classpath?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer yes, this is server-side code. the appengine devserver picks up the icu version in gwt-dev.jar, not the one from the icu-4.0.1.jar  but the appengine security sandbox prohibits the use of these classes somehow. What do you mean remove from DevMode classpath ? remove gwt-dev.jar ? then DevMode wont work anymore, right ?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer removing icu-4.0.1.jar gives java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.util.GregorianCalendar, so that's not an option :-( Also tried keeping icu-4.0.1.jar in the lib folder but without adding it in the eclipse build path, no luck.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer added a picture that shows how i figured it takes the wrong jar, because clicking the offending class in the stack trace shows that the line number is invalid for the gwt-dev.jar;

Comment: If it's server-side code, there's no need to have it in the classpath when launching DevMode, it should just live in `WEB-INF/lib` and/or `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: gwt-dev.jar is not in either WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes; it is part of the GWT SDK container which is included in my classpath but external to my workspace (btw, many thanks for helping out !!)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear; let's try this way: gwt-dev.jar is akin to Tomcat, Jetty, Glasfish, etc., it's in the classpath of what you launch; icu4j.jar is part of your webapp, it doesn't need to be in the classpath when launching the DevMode, it has to be in the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib`. The 2 JARs should be in different classloaders and shouldn't conflict with each others.

Comment: I understand that, but a default eclipse GWT project will include the GWT SDK on the classpath. AFAIK this will ALSO make gwt-dev.jar available to the classloader of the actual webapp, apart from acting as the servlet container (main function DevMode);

Comment: The "outer classloader" is only used as a fallback in the webapp (with a warning that the class was found outside the webapp's classloader), so it shouldn't be a problem: the webapp uses ICU from the icu4j JAR in `WEB-INF/lib`, DevMode uses ICU from the `gwt-dev.jar` (doesn't see the icu4j JAR if it's not in the classpath).

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, but it is. the webapp **insists** on using the version from `gwt-dev.jar` and this causes my problem with GAE. Question remaining: why, oh why ? I am trying to dig some deeper...

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't reproduce it (using Maven, but that's the same gwt-dev and DevMode); calling `new com.ibm.icu.util.GregorianCalendar().getType()` and `com.ibm.icu.text.Collator.getInstance().getDecomposition()`, with and without icu4j-4.0.1.jar in the classpath (before and after gwt-dev.jar), but always in `WEB-INF/lib`. So is your icu4j-4.0.1.jar correctly in `war/WEB-INF/lib` (and not `war/lib` as you typed in the title, for example); note that Eclipse will always search classes in the build path only, so that's not the way to _debug_ the situation.

Comment: thx for testing. if I figure out the prob, I will post back here (the title is a typo, it is of course `war/WEB-INF/lib`). prodution is not a problem, only DevMode.

Comment: Switching from OpenJDK to Oracle JDK fix it !! [It is not the first time][1] I ran into this :-/


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034900/appengine-devmode-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission-accessclassinp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from OpenJDK to Oracle JDK fixes it !! [It is not the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034900/appengine-devmode-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission-accessclassinp) I ran into issues with OpenJDK !